# Filling a table view from different DB tables in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, javafx

So, I need to fill a table-view from different DB tables connected through foreign keys, all I found is how to fill one from the same entity, do I need to create a different entity fill it with the required information, than fill the table view?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, show us some code.

Comment: If by ***entity*** you mean **data model**, then yes. Create a data model that holds all the information you collect from the various database tables and then use that to populate your `TableView`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look into creating [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) when sending entities to the view. By using DTOs you can easily create a custom object that contains the exact variables you want to show in your table, for example:

```
Entity1 entity1 = // your db function here

Entity2 entity2 = ...

TableDTO tableDTO = new TableDTO(
// use a constructor to combine your two entities into one object!
)

// now map your dto to your table located in the view
```

You wont be able to load multiple db entities at once unless you are using an [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html), or have set custom database functions inside your database. Both of these could return the exact object you want for your view, but I'd strongly suggest using the DTO pattern as it keeps your code simple and much eaiser to change. It also allows for much easier communcation between front and back end and keeps any confidential or unwanted db variables out of your application view.

It would help if you included some code from your application but hopefully this will be enough to fix your table views!

Comment: I'll do so once I'm home, I just wanted to have some idea about what should I do asap, because it is irritating me right now.